# node app download file from gcloud storage to client

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

Seems like this should have a canned answer of some sort, but I can't find anything.

The scenario is thus:

- I have a web page that lists files to download
- The files are located in gcloud storage
- I have a node server (express) app to reach into gcloud and fetch the file.

The web page js looks like this:

```
<script>
  function downloadFile(client, fn) {
    var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
      x.open("GET", "https://<domain>/fetch/" + client + '/' + fn, true);
      x.responseType = 'blob';
      x.onload=function(e){download(x.response, fn, "<content-type>" ); }
      x.send();
  }
</script>
```

It's doing a straight-up XMLHttpRequest() to the server with the requred fetch args.

The relevant part of the node js looks like this:

```
app.get('/fetch/:client/:filename', async function(req,rsp) {
  try {
    const storage = new Storage();
    const fileLoc = req.params.client + '/' + req.params.filename

    const options = {
      destination: './' + req.params.filename,
    };

    // Downloads the file
    let file = await storage
      .bucket('<bucket-name>')
      .file(fileLoc)

    let rstream = await file.createReadStream()
    .on("error", (err) => {
      console.log(" --> rstream error: " + err)
    })
    .on("response", (strRsp) => {
      console.log(' --> response received, sending headers.')
      rsp.setHeader('Content-Length', strRsp.headers['content-length'])
      rsp.setHeader('Content-Type', strRsp.headers['content-type'])
      rsp.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + req.params.filename)
    })
    .on("end", () => {
      console.log(' --> end received.')
      rsp.status(200).end()
      return true
    })
    .pipe(rsp)

  } catch(err) {
    console.log('download error: ' + err)
    rsp.status(400).send('failed') 
  } 
});
```

The thing is that it works, but it downloads the entire file (silently) before it puts up the save-as dialog.

Is there a way to put up the save dialog before downloading? (Perhaps I need to do the 'content-disposition' header on the client side...?)

Barring that, is there a way to reflect progress back to the web page js so that I can put up a dialog and show progress and maybe a cancel button until it is done and shows the save-as dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I went with the latter answer.  Doing the following:

- On download request, pop up a loading dialog with information about the download.
- Register a progress callback with the XMLHttpRequest instance
- Display the progress information in the dialog
- Dialog has a 'Cancel' button which calls 'abort()' on the XMLHttpRequest instance
- On completion (or abort) update the dialog and then close it via a timeout.